# What is the best character set for email field?

Tags: mysql

- binary
- utf8_bin
- utf8_unicode_ci
- utf8_general_ci

Which one is the best for storing unique emails in a MySql database?

*Note: That email field will be used for user login.*

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you looked at the [spec for email addresses](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.4.1)? That might help you out a little bit.

Comment: Now I checked the link. But I don't still get which one will be faster without any problem.
And are there any unicode characters in emails? I haven't seen before.

Comment: @Yilmaz, yes. It was [allowed for in 2003](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3490) and non-ascii TLDs were ["fast-tracked" through in 2009](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/idn)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An e-mail address is a piece of text. Therefore, **do not use binary**, use text.

**Utf8** seems to be a good choice. I am not sure what characters are supported for email addresses, but one can expect that there will increasingly be more unicode characters allowed in the future. Especially if you use utf8 elsewhere in your database, you don't have to switch from one encoding to another one, just use utf8 for everything.

As for choosing between **utf8_bin**, **utf8_unicode_ci** and **utf8_general_ci**, the difference is only the collation. This means it makes a difference when comparing the strings.

Now here you have to choose between what is allowed and what is normal. Normally, email addresses are case-insensitive, but they could be case-sensitive.

So if you use a unique index on your e-mail column, and want to allow for email addresses differing only in their capitalization, you should use **utf8_bin**, since collations ending with _ci mean "case-insensitive".

If you use a unique index and want to avoid emails differing only in their capitalization, then use **utf8_unicode_ci**.

That being said, I use **utf8_unicode_ci**. I want the db to be able to recognise johndoe@email.com and JohnDoe@email.com as the same address. It is much more useful than allowing for the possibility of addresses with same characters and different capitalization.