# Using latin character sets for storing emails and domain names in MySQL

Tags: mysql

The generic advice on stackoverflow is to use utf8 or utf8mb4 everywhere in MySQL, even for fields that will only ever contain latin characters.

- [What is the best character set for email field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195271/what-is-the-best-character-set-for-email-field)
- [best character set and collation for storing Tags, and URLs in MySQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260216/best-character-set-and-collation-for-storing-tags-and-urls-in-mysql-db)

To clarify, **for a column containing only latin characters**, would using utf8mb4:

1. ...result in a larger index and higher memory usage?
2. ...use more storage space when using column type varchar(100) or char(100)?
3. ...allow more than than 100 characters to be stored in column type varchar(100) or char(100)?

Answer (score 2):

It's 2017. Use `utf8mb4` and `VARCHAR(255)` for every generic "string" field unless you have a very compelling reason to deviate from that. Even pure Engish speakers love to use quirky non-Latin characters in situations like "¯\_(ツ)_/¯" and "ᕕ( ᐛ )ᕗ" or even .

Email addresses can contain non-ASCII characters in both the domain component, and in the local-part before the `@`. Whatever rules there were for these things seem to be getting thrown out the window one by one, so all bets are off for what the future holds. Hopefully the `@` stays, that's the only thing I'd count on.

Unless you have a system that is juggling billions of email addresses in memory then the storage cost of a `VARCHAR` is largely irrelevant. Remember, `VARCHAR(100)` and `VARCHAR(255)` take exactly the same amount of space for a 50-character string. The only thing the 100-length field does is get on someone's nerves when their email address is "too long" and gets trimmed arbitrarily.

Additionally, `VARCHAR` measures the length in *characters* and not *bytes*, a difference that is only relevant when multi-byte characters are involved. `bob@example.com` takes identical amounts of space in Latin-1, UTF-8 and UTF8MB4.

Don't use `CHAR` for variable length character fields. The 1980s have died. Let it go.

Comment: When you said email addresses can contain non-ASCII, I believe that those need to be punyencoded before being validated which makes them ASCII in the end. While I agree that storage costs are largely irrelevant, index/memory costs are still relevant given the small amount of ram available to db running in VM.

Comment: Define "small"? Even the most skimpy of VPS units these days comes with 512MB of memory and I've run a lot of things off of that footprint without any trouble. It's mostly a matter of tuning your database server to use an appropriate amount of memory and not get overly aggressive to the point of swapping. In the scheme of thing memory and storage related to email addresses are the least of your worries. Your bigger concerns will be how to manage logs, metrics, and the memory footprint of your application code.

Comment: It's generally best to store the email address as you're given it and let the email delivery process figure out how to send it. Doing the encoding yourself is not trivial, Punycoding is only half of the solution, the local-part uses an entirely different encoding method. If you're concerned about memory, Punycoding is going in the wrong direction, it's much larger than an equivalent UTF-8 representation.